# How to recompile less files on existing project

Tags: css, sass, less

So I have been using SCSS and Compass on all my projects. Super happy with it. However, just now I got an existing site built by a different team that needs to be updated and uses LESS. (The project also uses .ftl files which is also new to me)

Less syntax seems pretty similar and straight forward so I don't have an issue updating .less files, however how do I get it to "compile" to css so I can see my updates on the browser?

Comment: Docs are here: http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage.  Though it seems likely that Less may not be used in isolation, and you should inquire about an existing build process.  Is there a gulpfile or similar?  It may compile less among other things.

Answer (score 0):

[You] can invoke the compiler from the command-line, as such:

```
$ lessc styles.less
```

This will output the compiled CSS to stdout. To save the CSS result to a file of your choice use:

```
$ lessc styles.less styles.css
```

To output minified CSS you can use the clean-css plugin. When the plugin is installed, a minified CSS output is specified with --clean-css option:

```
$ lessc --clean-css styles.less styles.min.css
```

source: http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage

This is assuming that you have less installed through node.  Additionally, the previous developer could have been using a gulp file to compile it, so you will want to look at that as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to quickly convert it without installing any tools: http://less2css.org/

Personally I use http://koala-app.com/ for less, sass, compass and coffeescript. I especially like the auto compile option, just working on less files and the css file will be updated in the same folder at the same time.